# iPhone prevents scrolling on html5 video element

Tags: ios, html, video, html5-video

I have a html5 video element in my website:

```
 <video style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="video" controls preload="none" poster="media/start-image.jpg">
    <source src="media/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" title="mp4">
    <source src="media/video.webm" type="video/webm" title="webm">
</video>
```

When I open my website on the iPhone and try to scroll it is not possible. Only when I touch the small space between the video and the border of the phone.

Does someone has an idea to fix this issue?